# Parse the last 13 characters of the record through Alteryx or SQL

Tags: sql, parsing

I am trying to parse the last 13 characters on each of my records through Alteryx or SQL.

Could someone help me which tool/script I should use to solve this?

Record:

```
Serial Number                      Serial Number Orig
1 1-2MYGU7B YC07 S4B1343P07483     1-2MYGU7B YC07 S4B1343P07483
2 33_V_APC_1-2B4YKZ9 8W1428D09674  33_V_APC_1-2B4YKZ9 8W1428D09674
Output I want:   
Serial Number                      Serial Number Orig
1 1-2MYGU7B YC07                   1-2MYGU7B YC07 S4B1343P07483
2 S4B1343P07483                    1-2MYGU7B YC07 S4B1343P07483
3 33_V_APC_1-2B4YKZ9               33_V_APC_1-2B4YKZ9 8W1428D09674
4 8W1428D09674                     33_V_APC_1-2B4YKZ9 8W1428D09674
```

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? SQL Server, MySQL, Postgre?

Answer (score 1):

If this is SQL Server you would use the right() function:

```
SELECT right(SerialNumber, 13)
FROM  TableName
```

Comment: OP is not only asking for a string function, but also creating multiple rows from the result.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily accomplished by using the Formula tool in Alteryx. Just create a new field and then use the "Right" string expression on the original field to create a new one. By this way you will still have the original field and the new field.

The expression would be right([{org_field}],13).